# javascript with laravel blade template loop and sum

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, for-loop

i'm trying to do calculation with my table using java-script, but i don't know how to loop it with the rest of the id. right now i can only calculate single item how to make this multiple here is the result[image]

as you can see only id 1 get the result while id 2 is null how can i make this work here is my java script

```
function calc(){     
         var n1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n1').value);
         var n2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById('n2').value);
         var oper = document.getElementById('result').value = n1*4+n2; 
}

  <table id="my-table" class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr >
                      <th class="text">NAME</th>
                      <th class="text">A/P</th>
                      <th class="text">H/W</th>
                      <th class="text">Result</th>
                    </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                 @foreach($scores as $index => $score) 
                 <tr> 
                 <td>{{$score->lead->student_name}} <input type="hidden" name="scores[{{$loop->index}}][id]" value="{{$score->id}}"></td> 
                 <td style="text-align:center"><input id="n1" type="text" name="scores[{{$loop->index}}][jan_ap]" value="{{$score->jan_ap}}" class="input" autocomplete="off"></td> 
                 <td style="text-align:center"><input id="n2" type="text" name="scores[{{$loop->index}}][jan_hm]" value="{{$score->jan_hm}}"  class="input" autocomplete="off"></td> 
                 <td style="text-align:center"><input id="result" type="text" name="scores[{{$loop->index}}][result]" value="{{$score->result}}"  class="input" autocomplete="off"></td> 
                 </tr> 
                 @endforeach
                </tbody>
                </table><div class="form-group ">
                <button onclick="calc(); " type="submit">Submit</button>
                </div>
```

Comment: can you rewrite your question. You mention table, yet you show us an api with json. Should I make the assumption that you use the json to create a table using blade? Good idea to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: sorry try to read again my question the image i show u is the result of my return from my table im trying to calculate each id inside my table..

Comment: @Grace when you say table do you mean an HTML table, or your database table? You mention this javascript is within a blade template. If so, you might be approaching this problem the wrong way. It seems you're trying to read the values from within some DOM element but it would likely be easier for you to pass the data directly to javascript within your blade template see the docs here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#displaying-data

Here's the example too:

`
<script>
    var app = @json($n1Value);
</script>
`

Comment: after calculating, you want to show it in result textbox ?

Comment: yes if possible ..

Comment: then store it to my DB hehe

Comment: first of all you need to remove `id="n1"` because you can assign the same id in loop

Comment: if i remove the n1 how would it possible trigger the calculation?

Comment: let me write the table structure

Comment: this is connected to the table that we did last few days, is it possible to use php inside the controller to do calculation instead of java?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174956/discussion-between-rkj-and-grace).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From chat discussion and your controller code it found that, you want to add row with some formula and save the result in `results` field in database. So here we come up with code

Controller save method

```
$scores = $request->input('scores');

foreach($scores as $row){ 
    $score = Score::find($row['id']); 
    $score->jan_ap = $row['jan_ap']; 
    $score->jan_hm = $row['jan_hm']; 
    $score->result = round($row['jan_ap'] * 0.5) + ($row['result'] * 0.5); 
    $score->save(); 
}
```

Note: Remove your result text input fro blade template because it is not used anymore.

Comment: Yes absolute answer php is the way to calculate it and store it to the database thank you MAster @rkj for helping me solve this..and others who gave their answer ..

Answer (score 0):

I am answering this with some assumptions that I will make, since its not really clear from the question.

Assumption 1:
You have this table rendered using blade that gets Data from somewhere:

```
<div id="myTabDiv">
<table name="mytab" id="mytab1">
<tr> 
  <td>col1 Val1 (has ID)</td>
  <td>col2 Val2 (has jan_ap)</td>
  <td>col3 Val3 (has jan_hm)</td>
  <td>col4 Val4 (has result)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>col1 Val1 (has ID)</td>
  <td>col2 Val2 (has jan_ap)</td>
  <td>col3 Val3 (has jan_hm)</td>
  <td>col4 Val4 (has result)</td>
</tr>
```

Assumption 2: Yo have populated col 1-3 with values but you have a magical button, that when clicked calculates col4. Said button uses a JS function.

```
function calc(){    
var table = document.getElementById("mytab1");
for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
  //iterate through rows
  //rows would be accessed using the "row" variable assigned in the for loop
 for (var j = 0, col; col = row.cells[j]; j++) {
   //iterate through columns
   //columns would be accessed using the "col" variable assigned in the for loop
   //here you can do things like saying sum col[1] + col[2] and then input result in col[3]
   }  
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes sir assumption 2 is correct i will update my question..see the image

Comment: i'm targeting two col only which is jan_ap and jan_hm then populate the computation to col result.. is it possible?